# Do we have an obligation to our family members outside parental responsibility and filial piety?

Tags: ethics

Do we have an obligation to our family members outside parental responsibility and filial piety? So siblings, cousins, etc., can we reasonably expect them to have different sorts of moral agency for us than they do for others?

Comment: how do i know that they didn't clone everything too @AgentSmith ?

Comment: I dunno. For what it's worth. recommended reading: History of philosophy

Comment: true man @AgentSmith

Comment: now lots of things disappeared... @AgentSmith

Comment: @AgentSmith this is a very fruity hack https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459901/any-reason-why-i-am-told-i-have-no-internet-connection-when-i-type-gmail-com-int ahhhh

Comment: Gracias **loon** but not inta hacking although I have a few books on the topic. I prefer ... what's there ta prefer anyway, eh?

Comment: dywtf is a good one, even if implicily @AgentSmith

Comment: Family?  5 more to go ... 549 characters left? 

Comment: The extent and nature of family responsibility is heavily influenced by culture.  Which culture do you want the answer under?

Comment: if i have to choose i would just say EL philosophy @BobaFit if i had to